# why is "Permission denied"?

Tags: c, beagleboneblack

I have a function written in C that controls a DC motor through a Beaglebone Black

when I run the code, I get the following output

```
sh: 1: cannot create period: Permission denied
sh: 1: cannot create duty_cycle: Permission denied
sh: 1: cannot create enable: Permission denied
Done
```

Here is my code

```
//Function to start the DC motor
void motorstart (int speedlabelcounter)
{
    if (speedlabelcounter == 1){
        system("config-pin -a p8.07 hi");       //Required to be "hi" for the motor and the heating element to work
        system("config-pin -a p8.09 hi");
        system("config-pin -a p8.26 lo");
        //g_spawn_commwarning: unknown escape sequence: '\:'and_line_async("config-pin $
    
        //the speed of the motor can be controlled using a PWM output
        system("config-pin -a p9.21 pwm");
        system("cd /sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1 ; echo 0 > export");

        system("cd /sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0  ; echo 4000 > period");
        system("cd /sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0  ; echo 1000 > duty_cycle");
        //system("cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm-0:0/ ; echo 4000 > duty_cycle");
        system("cd /sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0  ; echo 1 > enable");
        printf("Done\n");
    }
}
```

How can fix I this?

Here is the updated code as @Barmar suggested

```
{
if (speedlabelcounter == 1){
system("config-pin -a p8.07 hi");       //Required to be "hi" for the motor and the heating element to work
system("config-pin -a p8.09 hi");
system("config-pin -a p8.26 lo");
//g_spawn_commwarning: unknown escape sequence: '\:'and_line_async("config-pin $


//the speed of the motor can be controlled using a PWM output
system("config-pin -a p9.21 pwm");
system("cd /sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1 ; echo 0 > export");
//system("cd pwmchip0");
//system("echo 0 > export");
//system("cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm-0\\:0/");
//char n1[] = "echo 4000 > period";
//char n2[] = "echo 1000 > duty_cycle";
//char n3[] = "echo 4000 > duty_cycle";
chdir("/sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0");
FILE *file = fopen("/sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0/period", "w"); fprintf(file, "4000\n"); fclose(file);
//system("cd /sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0  ; echo 1000 > duty_cycle");
//system("cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm-0:0/ ; echo 4000 > duty_cycle");
//system("cd /sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0  ; echo 1 > enable");
printf("Done\n");
}


}
```

Comment: Run as root perhaps? But are you sure you want to *create* these files?

Comment: FYI you can call `chdir()` from C instead of putting a `cd` command in every `system()` call.

Comment: It's also silly to use `system()` just to execute `echo`. C can write strings to files all by itself.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not creating these files. I'm changing their values. I tried to run sudo with no luck. How would you do it?

Comment: Since the files should presumably already exist, you're probably changing to the wrong directory.

Comment: Your shell seem to think these files do not exist there

Comment: There's nothing in `motorstart` that changes any values sent to the shell. So, all `system` calls could just go to an ordinary shell file (e.g.) `motorstart.sh` and just do `system("motorstart.sh")`

Comment: @Barmar My idea is to have C execute these lines in a terminal that's why I'm using system(). Are you saying that I can just have echo 4000 > period in this C file and it would execute?

Comment: `system()` doesn't use a terminal, it just calls the shell non-interactively.

Comment: I'm saying you would do `FILE *file = fopen("/sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0/period", "w"); fprintf(file, "4000\n"); fclose(file);`

Comment: Using `system` to invoke `cd` is pointless.  That will just change the directory of the shell that system uses, which exits before system returns.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's OK, he just wants it for the duration of the `echo` command afterward.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `echo 0 > export` creates the folder pwm-1:0 which I can see if I go to it manually and that folder contains the other folders period,duty_cycle and enable so I don't know why it wouldn't see them

Comment: Using multiple `system` calls to invoke different shell commands seems like a poor design decision.  Write a single script that does all of that and invoke it once with `system`.  (Or, just skip the C code completely and use a shell script!)

Comment: @WilliamPursell This appears to be just one function in a larger C program.

Comment: First do `chdir("/sys/devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1/pwm-1:0");` then you can just do `fopen("period", "w");`

Comment: @Barmar I get Segmentation fault

Comment: That's because it gets an error trying to create the file, for the same reason as your `system()` commands.

Comment: You still have to fix the original problem that you're using the wrong directory.

Comment: @Barmar To my understading `echo 0 > export` is making pwm-1:0. Then I want to use `echo 4000 > period` to change the value inside the period file that is already there

Comment: @Barmar Please look at the updated code

Comment: You understand that the word after `>` is a filename, right? So it means it's trying to write to a file named `export` in the directory named `pwm-1:0`

Comment: It seems like you don't understand some basic principles. The whole reason for doing `chdir()` is so you don't have to repeat the directory path in `fopen()`.

Comment: Changing from `system` to `fopen` won't solve the problem if you don't figure out what the correct directory and filenames are.